# Redirect Other Jsp JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I did a Login with Javascript which is very simple but i need redirect to other page after validate user and password . I have the following code but this opens a lash and i need to redirect to other jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function loginUser()
{
    var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
    var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

    if(username == "JBARBA" && password == "123")
    {
        alert('Bienvenido Jose Carlos Barba Gutierrez');
        url = 'menu.jsp';
        window.open(url);
    }else{
        alert('Usuario y/o Password Incorrectos');    
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for location.replace('newurl');

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location

I hope, that you don't want to rely on this code.
There is absolutly **NO** security in this login.